# Substituir palavras ao importar no ListView

Tags: delphi

Estou importando um arquivo *.DAT* em um *ListView*, preciso que antes que seja feita a importação o programa procure a expressão `{keyword}` nos itens e que essa mesma expressão seja substituída pelo texto de um *Edit*.

Exemplo:

> **Item original no arquivo .dat**: "As 7 maravilhas do {keyword}"
>
> **Texto do Edit**: "Emagrecimento"
>
> **Item importado no Listview**: "As 7 maravilhas do Emagrecimento"

E da mesma forma com os outros itens.

Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Código:

```
  procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  procedure ListView1Data(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
  procedure BtnLoadFromFileClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure LoadFromFile(AFileName: string);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  TMyRecord = record
    name: string;
    address: string;
    floatfield: Single;
    integerfield: Integer;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  MyList: TList<TMyRecord>;
```

Continuação do Código:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyList := TList<TMyRecord>.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyList.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1Data(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
  Item.Caption := MyList[Item.Index].name;
  Item.SubItems.Add(MyList[Item.Index].address);
  Item.SubItems.Add(FloatToStr(MyList[Item.Index].floatfield));
  Item.SubItems.Add(IntToStr(MyList[Item.Index].integerfield));
end;

procedure TForm1.LoadFromFile(AFileName: string);
var
  MyFileStream: TFileStream;
  MyBinaryReader: TBinaryReader;
  temprecord: TMyRecord;
  I, TempNumber: Integer;
begin
  MyFileStream := TFileStream.Create(AFileName, fmOpenRead);
  MyBinaryReader := TBinaryReader.Create(MyFileStream,
    TEncoding.Unicode, false);
  MyList.Clear;
  try
    TempNumber := MyBinaryReader.ReadInteger;
    for I := 0 to TempNumber - 1 do
    begin
      temprecord.name := MyBinaryReader.ReadString;
      temprecord.address := MyBinaryReader.ReadString;
      temprecord.floatfield := MyBinaryReader.ReadSingle;
      temprecord.integerfield := MyBinaryReader.ReadInteger;
      MyList.Add(temprecord);
    end;
    ListView1.Items.Count := MyList.Count;
    MyBinaryReader.Close;
  finally
    MyBinaryReader.Free;
    MyFileStream.Free;
  end;
end;


procedure TForm1.BtnLoadFromFileClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
    LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode utilizar o seguinte código, no qual usei dois `memos` e um `botão` para simular o que precisa, basta adaptar ao seu código. Tentei detalhar ao máximo possível o código mas alguma dúvida comunique.

**Código:**

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Escreo no memo1 algumas frases.
  Memo1.Lines.Add('As 7 maravilhas do {keyword}');
  Memo1.Lines.Add('As 7 maravilhas do nada.');
  Memo1.Lines.Add('As 7 maravilhas do {exemplo} e arredores.');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i, APos: Integer;
    ALine, AText, AWord, AResult: String;
begin
  //O for ai ler ler todas as linhas do memo uma a uma
  for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
    Begin
      //Limpo variáveis
      AText := '';
      AWord := '';
      AResult := '';
      //Vai ler uma minha linha do memo
      ALine := Memo1.Lines[i];

      //Enquanto a linha tiver alguma coisa faz...
      While (Trim(ALine) <> '') do
        Begin
          //Pega a posição de uma nova palavra 
          APos := Pos(' ', ALine);
          //Se encontrou alguma palavra faz...
          if (APos > 0) then
            begin
              //Pega a palavra
              AWord := Trim(AnsiMidStr(ALine, 1, APos - 1));
              //Apaga-a da linha
              Delete(ALine, 1, APos);
            end
          else
            Begin
              //Se não tem mais de uma palavra então pega o resto da linha
              AWord := ALine;
              ALine := '';
            End;

          //verifica se a palavra precisa ser substituída
          if (Trim(AWord) = '{keyword}') then
            Begin
              //Substitui '{keyword}' por 'pais'  
              AResult := AText + ' pais ' + ALine;
              Break;
            End
          else if (Trim(AWord) = '{exemplo}') then
            Begin
              //Substitui '{exemplo}' por 'mundo' 
              AResult := AText + ' mundo ' + ALine;
              Break;
            End
          else
            Begin
              //Se não precisa de substituir junta a palavra ha nova linha 
              AText := AText +' '+ AWord;
            End;
        End;

      //Escreve no memo2 o resultado
      if (Trim(AResult) <> '') then
        Begin
          //Se encontrou uma palavra para substituir
          Memo2.Lines.Add(AResult);
        End
      else
        Begin
          //Se encontrou nada para substituir
          Memo2.Lines.Add(AText);
        End;
    End;
end;
```

Comment: Muito bom.
O teu código acabou dando a ideia de usar a função String Replace que funcionou da mesma forma.