# Receber string JSON via Socket

Tags: json, delphi

Estou recebendo um fluxo com strings JSON e estou exibindo em um TMemo. Ocorre que não estou conseguindo processar os JSON corretamente pois nem sempre vem a mesma quantidade de caracteres do servidor.
Precisaria processar os JSON e exibir os resultados em outro TMemo. Ouvi falar em buffer, streams etc mas não tenho familiaridade com os mesmos.

Obs: Uso TClientSocket

```
procedure TForm1.csClienteRead(Sender: TObject; Socket:  TCustomWinSocket);
var
 data: String;
begin
 data := Socket.ReceiveText;
 memoResults.Lines.Add(data);     
end;
```

Assim que ligo a conexão do Cliente recebo esses dados:

```
{ "age" : "0", "camera" : "0", "direction" : "===", "id" : "12", "plate" : "DEMOPLATE", "strength" : "0.66 - 1.00 0.90 1.00 0.66 1.00 0.90 1.00", "systemName" : "AUTOPARKING", "timestamp" : "1508328838" }
{ "age" : "0", "camera" : "0", "direction" : "===", "id" : "11", "plate" : "DEMOPLATE", "strength" : "0.66 - 1.00 0.90 1.00 0.66 1.00 0.90 1.00", "systemName" : "AUTOPARKING", "timestamp" : "1508328838" }
{ "age" : "1", "camera" : "0", "direction" : "===", "id" : "10", "plate" : "DEMOPLATE", "strength" : "0.66 - 1.00 0.90 1.00 0.66 1.00 0.90 1.00", "systemName" : "AUTOPARKING", "timestamp" : "1508328837" }
{ "age" : "1", "camera" : "0", "direction" : "===", "id" : "9", "plate" : "DEMOPLATE", "strength" : "0.66 - 1.00 0.90 1.00 0.66 1.00 0.90 1.00", "systemName" : "AUTOPARKING", "timestamp" : "1508328837" }
{ "age" : "2", "camera" : "0", "direction" : "===", "id" : "8", "plate" : "DEMOPLATE", "strength" : "0.66 - 1.00 0.90 1.00 0.66 1.00 0.90 1.00", "systemName" : "AUTOPARKING", "timestamp" : "1508328836" }
{ "age" : "2", "camera" : "0", "direction" : "===", "id" : "7", "plate" : "DEMOPLATE", "strength" : "0.66 - 1.00 0.90 1.00 0.66 1.00 0.90 1.00", "systemName" : "AUTOPARKING", "timestamp" : "1508328836" }
{ "age" : "3", "camera" : "0", "direction" : "===", "id" : "6", "plate" : "DEMOPLATE", "strength" : "0.66 - 1.00 0.90 1.00 0.66 1.00 0.90 1.00", "systemName" : "AUTOPARKING", "timestamp" : "1508328835" }
{ "age" : "3", "camera" : "0", "direction" : "===", "id" : "5", "plate" : "DEMOPLATE", "strength" : "0.66 - 1.00 0.90 1.00 0.66 1.00 0.90 1.00", "systemName" : "AUTOPARKING", "timestamp" : "1508328835" }
{ "age" : "4", "camera" : "0", "direction" : "===", "id" : "4", "plate" : "DEMOPLATE", "strength" : "0.66 - 1.00 0.90 1.00 0.66 1.00 0.90 1.00", "systemName" : "AUTOPARKING", "timestamp" : "1508328834" }
{ "age" : "4", "camera" : "0", "direction" : "===", "id" : "3", "plate" : "DEMOPLATE", "strength" : "0.66 - 1.00 0.90 1.00 0.66 1.00 0.90 1.00", "systemName" : "AUTOPARKING", "timestamp" : "1508328834" }
{ "age" : "16402735", "camera" : "0", "direction" : ">>>", "id" : "0", "plate" : "DEMOPLATE", "strength" : "0.66 - 1.00 0.90 1.00 0.66 1.00 0.90 1.00", "systemName" : "AUTOPARKING", "timestamp" : "1491926103" }
{ "age" : "16402735", "camera" : "0", "direction" : "===", "id" : "2", "plate" : "DEMOPLATE", "strength" : "0.66 - 1.00 0.90 1.00 0.66 1.00 0.90 1.00", "systemName" : "AUTOPARKING", "timestamp" : "1491926103" }
{ "age" : "16402736", "camera" : "0", "direction" : "===", "id" : "1", "plate" : "DEMOPLATE", "strength" : "0.66 - 1.00 0.90 1.00 0.66 1.00 0.90 1.00", "systemName" : "AUTOPARKING", "timestamp" : "1491926102" }
{ "age" : "16402736", "camera" : "0", "direction" : "===", "id" : "0", "plate" : "DEMOPLATE", "strength" : "0.66 - 1.00 0.90 1.00 0.66 1.00 0.90 1.00", "systemName" : "AUTOPARKING", "timestamp" : "1491926102" }
```

Após isso começa a vir linha por linha mas as vezes vem tudo junto sem quebras de linha. Eu preciso de 1 JSON por vez senão o sistema não processa.

Comment: Qual é mais o menos a estrutura do JSON? Adiciona uma resposta do JSON na pergunta

Comment: Veja se isso ajuda vai precisar de algo tipo isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/237277/substituir-palavras-ao-importar-no-listview/237354#237354

Comment: Exatamente como o @Tmc mencionou, poste a estrutura do JSON que esta recebendo, caso contraria esta muito ampla sua pergunta!

Comment: @Tmc Editei a pergunta com o retorno do JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com o seguinte código vai organizar o JSON desta forma, exemplo:

> age:0
> camera:0
> direction:===
> id:12
>   plate:DEMOPLATE
> strength:0.66 - 1.00 0.90 1.00 0.66 1.00 0.90 1.00
> systemName:AUTOPARKING
> timestamp:1508328838

Usei dois memos e um botão para o código funcionar, no memo1 colei a resposta de JSON depois no evento onCLick do botão crei o código para tratamento do texto, e escrevo no memo2.

Código:

```
var APos: Integer;
    AText, AWord, AResult: String;
begin
  AResult := '';

  AText := Memo1.Text;
  While (Trim(AText) <> '') do
    Begin
      APos := Pos('"', AText);
      if (APos > 0) then
        begin
          AWord := Trim(AnsiMidStr(AText, 1, APos - 1));
          Delete(AText, 1, APos);
        end
      else
        Begin
          AWord := Trim(AText);
          AText := '';
        End;

      if (AWord <> ',') and (AWord <> '{') and (AWord <> '}') and (AWord <> '} {') then
        Begin
          AResult := AResult + AWord;
          AWord := '';
        End;

      if (AWord <> '') then
        Begin
          Memo2.Lines.Add(AResult);
          AResult := '';
        End;
    End;
End;
```

Se precisar das respostas apenas separadas, assim:

> { "age" : "0", "camera" : "0", "direction" : "===", "id" : "12", "plate" : "DEMOPLATE", "strength" : "0.66 - 1.00 0.90 1.00 0.66 1.00 0.90 1.00", "systemName" : "AUTOPARKING", "timestamp" : "1508328838" }

Use o seguinte código:

```
var APosB, APosE: Integer;
    AText, AResult: String;
begin
  AResult := '';
  AText := Memo1.Text;
  While (Trim(AText) <> '') do
    Begin
      APosB := Pos('{', AText);
      APosE := Pos('}', AText);
      if (APosB > 0) and (APosE > 0) then
        begin
          AResult := Trim(AnsiMidStr(AText, APosB, APosE - 1));
          Delete(AText, 1, APosE);
        end
      else
        Begin
          AResult := Trim(AText);
          AText := '';
        End;

      Memo2.Lines.Add(AResult);
    End;
end;
```

Alguma dúvida no código avise que eu esclareço.

Comment: Ficou bom, mas ainda tem alguns ajustes. vou mandar as telas com os resultados. http://www.menq.com.br/erro.jpg (aqui está certo) http://www.menq.com.br/erro1.jpg (aqui precisa ajustar). Na segunda imagem parece que ainda falta remover mais algumas chaves.

Comment: Usando a segunda dica fica assim  http://www.menq.com.br/erro2.jpg  estranho é que as vezes fecha a ultima chave do JSON e as vezes não fecha.

Comment: estava pensando... pode ser o servidor que manda strings incompletas. derrepente uma maneira seria usar buffer e so liberar quando tiver todo o tamanho da remessa. mas nao saberia como fazer isso.

Comment: @EzequielTavares existe sim possibilidade de o servidor estar a "comer" caracteres ou a ver separados o ideal para perceber o que está acontecer era descarregar tudo em um memo depois fazer o tratamento para outro e ver o resultado se esta correto

Comment: Na verdade quando eu clico para abrir a conexão ele manda tudo que tá armazenado e da erro. Depois ele vai mandando os resultados separados aí reconhece legal.

Comment: Obrigado... com mais algumas alterações deu tudo certo!